# \XeTeXinterchartoks fails when applied to non-ASCII characters

Tags: xetex, arabxetex

In the following code `\XeTeXinterchartoks` fails when applied to non-ASCII characters. Any help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\chardef\stretchchar="0640

\newXeTeXintercharclass \charclassAen
\newXeTeXintercharclass \charclassBen

\XeTeXcharclass `\A \charclassAen
\XeTeXcharclass `\C \charclassAen

\XeTeXcharclass `\B \charclassBen
\XeTeXcharclass `\D \charclassBen

\newXeTeXintercharclass \charclassAar
\newXeTeXintercharclass \charclassBar

\chardef\Aar="062A % ت
\chardef\Bar="0641 % ف
\chardef\Car="0647 % ه
\chardef\Dar="0649 % ى
\chardef\Ear="064A % ي
\chardef\Far="06CC % ی
\chardef\Gar="FBFE % ﯾ
\chardef\Har="FBFD % ﯽ
\chardef\Iar="FEF0 % ﻰ
\chardef\Jar="FEF3 % ﻳ

\XeTeXcharclass \Aar \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Bar \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Car \charclassAar 
\XeTeXcharclass \Dar \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Ear \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Far \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Gar \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Har \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Iar \charclassAar
\XeTeXcharclass \Jar \charclassAar

\XeTeXcharclass \Aar \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Bar \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Car \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Dar \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Ear \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Far \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Gar \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Har \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Iar \charclassBar
\XeTeXcharclass \Jar \charclassBar

\newcommand \stretchitEN{
    \XeTeXinterchartokenstate 1 %
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \charclassAen \charclassBen = {{\color{red}\stretchchar\stretchchar\stretchchar}}
}

\newcommand \stretchitAR{
    \XeTeXinterchartokenstate 1 %
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \charclassAen \charclassBen = {{\color{red}\stretchchar\stretchchar\stretchchar}}
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \charclassAar \charclassBar = {{\color{red}\stretchchar\stretchchar\stretchchar}}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
{
\stretchitEN{}
Test is a test. CDTest is a test. Test is a test. ABTest is a test.
Test is a test. CDTest is a test. Test is a test. ABTest is a test.
Test is a test. CDTest is a test. Test is a test. ABTest is a test. 
}

{
\stretchitAR{}
\Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar AB \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar CD \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar
\Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar CD \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar AB \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar
\Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar CD \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar CD \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar
\Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar CD \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar AB \Far\Dar\Far\Aar\Jar\Iar \Har\Ear\Dar\Ear\Aar
}

\end{document}
```

Its output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TSE. :D

Your code is not correct. You can't put the same chars in both classes. 
You've to make a new rule for every possible situation.

To show you that's your code's problem not the \XeTeXinterchartoks with non-ASCII characters, put the following lines in your code and then see the output.

```
\XeTeXcharclass `\B \charclassAen
\XeTeXcharclass `\D \charclassAen
\XeTeXcharclass `\A \charclassBen
\XeTeXcharclass `\C \charclassBen
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, but this was not mentioned in XeTeX references. Do you know a better reference guide for XeTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: I don't know but I really eager to know. I think you might ask @khaledHosny. If you find a descriptive reference, I would be glad to know about that.